# Transit visa requirements for Dammam, Saudi Arabia

Tags: transit-visas, eu-citizens, saudi-arabia, dmm

We have bought two separate tickets with Wizz Air, first from Abu Dhabi to Dammam followed by Dammam to Budapest. The layover is 4 hours, with no checked luggage (only carry-ons). Do we need visa for Dammam as Czech citizens?

Comment: I wonder why kiwi.com (or their offshoots) are so eager to sell self-connections in Dammamm

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a visa for Saudi Arabia, as it is not a connecting flight. You can take the visa as eVisa, as Czech citizens are eligible for eVisa. It is a 1 year multiple entry visa and you can possibly use it for return as well.

If you don't have a visa, then the airline will be denying you boarding, even if you are not planning to get out of airport.

Link to eVisa - https://visa.visitsaudi.com/